# Is it possible to retrieve the description of a youtube video without authenticating through the API?

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write a Greasemonkey script to extract the description of a Youtube video and insert it into another site that makes use of embedded videos.

The only way I've found to do this is to use the API to call all the data for the video. I think this is an overcomplicated way to do this, so I want to create a script that doesn't require authentication and can scrape the description.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info` service that returns an [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)-compatible `&`-separated string of various video parameters, including `title`.

```
function getYoutubeVideoTitle(id, callback) {
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=' + id,
        onload: function(r) {
            var encoded = (r.responseText.match(/(^|&)title=(.*?)(&|$)/) || [])[2] || '';
            callback(decodeURIComponent(encoded.replace(/\+/g, ' ')));
        }
    });
}
```

```
getYoutubeVideoTitle('jE51HWPz1l8', function(title) {
    console.log(title);
});
```

> Specsavers Boiler Advert - 2017

To get all parameters in an object split the response by `&` and split each element by `=` as key/value:

```
function getYoutubeVideoData(id, callback) {
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=' + id,
        onload: function(response) {
            var data = {};
            response.responseText.split('&').forEach(function(param) {
                param = param.split('=');
                data[param[0]] = decodeURIComponent(param[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
            });
            callback(data);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Notes.

In modern browsers [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) provides a much more convenient access:

```
        onload: (r) => callback(new URLSearchParams(r.responseText).get('title'));
```

```
        onload: (r) => {
            var data = {};
            for (var entry of new URLSearchParams(r.responseText).entries())
                data[entry[0]] = entry[1];
            callback(data);
        }
```

The code assumes no duplicate keys in the response, which is true for get_video_info service.

To get video download links and more info in the response modify the request URL:

```
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=' + id +
             '&hl=en_US&html5=1&el=embedded&eurl=' + encodeURIComponent(location.href),
```

Comment: Using URLSearchParams, do I then use Greasemonkey to position the response where I want it in the webpage as usual?

Comment: URLSearchParams is just a convenience that upgrades manual string splitting, it's not related to anything else.